# How to add an auxiliary part in the name of a proof?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

With

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,hyperref,mathtools,amsthm}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue
}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{theorem} \label{thm} ~
\begin{enumerate}
\item Part 1
\item Part 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof} [Proof of \cref{thm}]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

I have

[image]

I would like to have something like `Proof of Theorem 1[1]` rather than `Proof of Theorem 1`. This allows more precise referencing. I tried the syntax `[Proof of \cref{thm}[1]]` but to no avail.

Could you elaborate on how to realize my intention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to define a new label format for `theorem` using `\creflabelformat{theorem}{#2#1[#1]#3}`. For more details you could check the [manual](https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf) at page 12 in section 8.1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,hyperref,mathtools,amsthm}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue
}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\creflabelformat{theorem}{#2#1[#1]#3}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{theorem} \label{thm} ~
\begin{enumerate}
\item Part 1
\item Part 2
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof} [Proof of \cref{thm}]
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]